# ModelForm ManyToMany fields display only assigned values

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django ModelForm to display information about hardware articles. Everything goes fine, but when it comes to many2many fields, default behavior is to display every instance of the related model. I need to display only the assigned one, for example if my article A is related to server S, I'd like to display only S, not a list with Server A, server B etc ... I went through the official doc and various forums but I have no clue how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[What I got now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo5dt.png)

Below are models.py and forms.py

```
class ArticleHW(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nom", max_length=200)
    reference = models.CharField(
        "Référence",
        max_length=200,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None
    )
    version = models.CharField(
        "Version",
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
    serie_num = models.CharField(
        "Numéro de série",
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    armoire_pos = models.CharField(
        "Position armoire",
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        "Description",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
    date_obs = models.DateField(
        "Date d'obsolescence",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        symmetrical=False,
        verbose_name="Hardware parent"
    )
    HW_comp = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name="Hardware compatible"
    )
    doc_link = models.ManyToManyField(
        'ArticleDoc',
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name="Lien documentation"
    )
    equip_link = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Equipement',
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Lien équipement",
        through='QuantiteHW'
    )
    group = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Groupe',
        default=3,
        symmetrical=False,
        verbose_name="Groupe"
    )


class HWUploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ArticleSW
        fields = ['name', 'reference', 'version', 'serie_num', 'group', 'doc_link']
        widgets = {
            'name' : TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
            'reference': TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            'version': TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            'serie_num': TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        }
```

Comment: It is very hard to picture your problem. Can you please provide the relevant code snippets?

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of what I have now, instead of select list I'd like to display only the assigned value (the one with blue background in my screenshot).

Comment: It's still doesn't help a lot. We need to see your models.py and eventually your forms.py. You can cut out irrelevant parts. When you add a group, should it restrict the list of groups only to the assigned ones?

Comment: I've uploaded my code. For groups, the user can choose one in the select list, but for doc_link he should only see the documents assigned to this item, not a list of every document in the database.

Comment: In your models you have a class `ArticleHW`, but in your form you refer to the model `ArticleSW`. Is this just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the option `limit_choices_to`. How it should be exactly implemented in your code, depends on the model `ArticleDoc` and its properties. An example would be:

```
class ArticleHW(models.Model):
# ...
doc_link = models.ManyToManyField(
    'ArticleDoc',
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    verbose_name="Lien documentation",
    limit_choices_to={'property': 'value'}
)
# ...
```

Here is a lint to the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to